# Upsert a table to existing splayed table in memory leading to error: `type (Q/KDB+)

Tags: kdb, upsert

I'm to new Q language and KDB+ database. I'm having trouble upserting another table to an existing splayed table in memory.

I have the following table called `temp` which is then saved as a splayed table in `` `:temp ``

```
col1 col2 col3
--------------
a    0    1   
b    1.5  2.5 
c    1.1  2.2 
d    0.99 0.98
```

The directory structure of the splayed table:

```
temp
|  .d
|  col1
|  col2
|  col3
|  sym
```

Let's say I have another table `new`

```
new: ([] col1:`e`f`g; col2:1.0 1.1 1.1; col3: 2.25 2.20 2.70)
```

**My question is: How do we upsert `new` to `` `:temp ``?**

I've read https://code.kx.com/q/ref/upsert/, but the example given there is only upserting one record (not an entire table). I've tried `` `:temp upsert (`sym?new) `` which leads to `type` error.

### Edit (All commands I run)

```
q)temp: ([] col1:`a`b`c`d; col2:0.0 1.5 1.1 0.99; col3: 1.0 2.5 2.2 0.98)
q)`:temp/ set .Q.en[`:.;temp]
`:temp/
q)new: ([] col1:`e`f`g; col2:1.0 1.1 1.1; col3: 2.25 2.20 2.70)
q)`:temp upsert new
'type
  [0]  `:temp upsert new
              ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enumerate any symbol type columns, either "manually" using [enum extend](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/enum-extend/)

```
q)`:temp/ set([]col1:`:sym?`a`b;col2:1 2f;col3:10 20f);
q)`:temp upsert([]col1:`:sym?`e`f`g;col2:1.0 1.1 1.1;col3:2.25 2.20 2.70);
q)get`:sym
`a`b`e`f`g
q)get`:temp
col1 col2 col3
--------------
a    1    10
b    2    20
e    1    2.25
f    1.1  2.2
g    1.1  2.7
```

or using one of the helper functions such as [.Q.en](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qen-enumerate-varchar-cols)

```
q)`:temp/ set .Q.en[`:.;([]col1:`A`B;col2:1 2f;col3:10 20f)];
q)`:temp upsert .Q.en[`:.;([]col1:`e`f`g;col2:1.0 1.1 1.1;col3:2.25 2.20 2.70)];
q)get`:sym
`A`B`e`f`g
q)get`:temp
col1 col2 col3
--------------
A    1    10
B    2    20
e    1    2.25
f    1.1  2.2
g    1.1  2.7
```

There are other things to watch out for when upserting to persisted files such as

- any files with attributes applied will have those attributes removed by the upsert operation (except for sorted which will be preserved if the list remains in ascending order)
- If any files with attributes are compressed, they will be rewritten uncompressed unless you take steps to ensure otherwise

```
q)(`:groupedVector;17;2;6)set `g#1 2 3;
q)-21!`:groupedVector
compressedLength  | 113
uncompressedLength| 240
algorithm         | 2i
logicalBlockSize  | 17i
zipLevel          | 6i
q)attr get`:groupedVector
`g
q)
q)`:groupedVector upsert 4 5;
q)get `:groupedVector
1 2 3 4 5
q)-21!`:groupedVector       // compression lost
q)attr get`:groupedVector   // attribute lost
`
```

- It's up to the developer to ensure compatibility between column files on disk & the data to be appended - otherwise you could end with column files of different lengths e.g.

```
q)`:temp/ set([]char:"ab";long:1 2);
q)`:temp upsert ("c";3);
q)`:temp upsert ("d";4i);
'type
  [0]  `:temp upsert ("d";4i);
              ^
q)get`:temp/char
"abcd"
q)get`:temp/long
1 2 3
```

Comment: Is there any way to upsert without "manually typing" the table definition? Let's say I have a splayed table with 100 rows and I want to upsert a million records, it would be impossible to manually type something like `([]col1:\`:sym?\`e\`f\`g;col2:1.0 1.1 1.1;col3:2.25 2.20 2.70)` right?

Comment: I am expecting something like `\`:temp upsert (colnames ! entries)` where `colnames` is `\`col1\`col2\`col3` in the example above. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: @Meinung The commands will work the same with just the table name e.g. `\`:temp/ set .Q.en[\`:.;temp]`, also I noticed the way you are saving your enumerations means that you are saving the sym file in the same location as the columns, make sure it's the same level as the table directory i.e. use the example above, and don't use `\`:temp/ set .Q.en[\`:temp;temp]`

Comment: @CameronMcKee Thank you for the suggestion. But I'm still not able to upsert new records to `\`:temp`. I've tried `\`:temp/ upsert new` suggested by @Leah Carragher but I still get `\`type` error. I apologize if things I'm asking are too trivial

Comment: @Meinung can you provide all the commands you're running? Including both table definitions. There might be something there that's causing the `\`type` error

Comment: @CameronMcKee I've added all of the commands in my first post

Comment: Oh, I'm finally able to upsert without getting a `\`type` error by `\`:temp upsert .Q.en[\`:.] new`!! Thanks a lot for all of your help guys

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `temp` saved as a splayed table, you can upsert `new` to it by using the following:

```
q) new:([]col1:`e`f`g;col2:1.0 1.1 1.1;col3:2.25 2.20 2.70)
q) `:temp upsert new
`:temp
q) get`:temp
col1 col2 col3
--------------
a    0    1
b    1.5  2.5
c    1.1  2.2
d    0.99 0.98
e    1    2.25
f    1.1  2.2
g    1.1  2.7
```

You are then able to see the desired result. If you leave the q session and load it in to a new session, you will see that this has been saved.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting a `\`:type` error. I suspect there is an incorrect code when I save `temp` as a splayed table. Is this a correct way to save a splayed table? `temp:.Q.en[\`:temp;temp]` followed by `\`:temp/ set temp`